# Swift Package Manager does not support provisioning profiles

Tags: ios, xcode, azure-devops, pipeline, xcode14

I had a pipeline configured in azure devops that uploaded apps to testflight, but when I updated to xcode 14, my pipeline has returned the following error for SPMs with resources:

```
note: Building targets in dependency order
/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DesignSystem-ghbaswrmnadtfsdcsbiiyhnaybhc/SourcePackages/checkouts/firebase-ios-sdk/Package.swift: error: Firebase_FirebaseInAppMessaging_iOS does not support provisioning profiles. Firebase_FirebaseInAppMessaging_iOS does not support provisioning profiles, but provisioning profile Design System has been manually specified. Set the provisioning profile value to "Automatic" in the build settings editor. (in target 'Firebase_FirebaseInAppMessaging_iOS' from project 'Firebase')
** BUILD FAILED **

##[error]Error: The process '/usr/bin/xcodebuild' failed with exit code 65
```

Any SPM with resources gives me this error, my tasks until now are:

```
- task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
          displayName: 'Install .p12 certificate'
          inputs:
            certSecureFile: $(project.p12)
            certPwd: $(project.p12.password)
            keychain: 'temp'
- task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
          displayName: 'Install .mobileprovision certificate'
          inputs:
            provisioningProfileLocation: 'secureFiles'
            provProfileSecureFile: Design_System.mobileprovision
- task: Xcode@5
          displayName: 'Xcode Build'
          inputs:
            actions: 'clean build'
            sdk: $(project.sdk)
            scheme: '$(schemeName)'
            configuration: $(project.configuration.release)
            xcWorkspacePath: $(project.workspace)
            xcodeVersion: 'specifyPath'
            xcodeDeveloperDir: '/Applications/Xcode_14.3.1.app/'
            archivePath: '$(system.defaultworkingdirectory)'
            exportPath: 'output/$(project.sdk)/$(project.configuration.release)'
            exportMethod: 'app-store'
            signingOption: 'manual'
            useXcpretty: false
            packageApp: true
            signingIdentity: '$(APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY)'
            provisioningProfileUuid: '$(APPLE_PROV_PROFILE_UUID)'
            args: '-verbose'
```

I already tried to put some arguments in this task, but without result. I've tried the arguments: `CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY`, `DEVELOPMENT_TEAM`, `-UseModernBuildSystem=0`, `-allowProvisioningUpdates`, `TEAM_ID`, `-resolvePackageDependencies`, `-forceResolvedPackageVersions`, `CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=Yes`, `CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=No`, some of the arguments even disable the code signing that I will need to upload to testflight.
How can I fix or workaround this issue?

Comment: It's been a few months.  Any success?

Comment: How did you solved this? I have the same issue with firebase messaging